# Magento 2 - How to Manage different theme for different store?

Tags: magento2, multistore, multidomain, multi-website

We have multi Stores site. And we have created 4 stores on a single website and we want a different design for all the stores.

**Can anyone tell how to set different themes for the different store.?**

And also I want to set the different domain for the different store in single Magento.

If anyone knows how to set multi stores with multi-domains? Then, please let us know.

Your help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Multi store is one of the great features that magento has out of the box.

So, to configure each new store you've created with a different domain, you can change it on Stores > Configuration > Web > Base URLs and Base URLs(Secure) sections.

[image: Url configuration section]

Once being in URL section, above you have "Store View" option, just change to the store you want to customize configuration.

[image: Scope configuration]

Once store scope is changed you can add your custom domain in URL sections.

BUT above is just the how to configure custom url in magento side, there are more things to do in server side to create new domains and associde it to magento's store code, so a detailed information of this can be found in devdocs:

- NGINX:
  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/multi-site/ms_nginx.html
- APACHE:
  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html

Hope the information is useful!

Comment: we have tried your solution. But, it's not working for me.