# How to Install different themes for different store?

Tags: magento2, multistore, multi-website, multidomain

I just saw this question here: "How to Manage different theme for different store?" and i got a clear answer.
Now my question is, how can i choose which theme to install at different storeS, so i can have different stores with a unique theme different from the others?

Because if i try to change the domain up there (at SCOPE as shown on the answer of the question that i wrote that i got the answer), at every configuration of different themes i already installed, i have the same thing checked "use website". But the website is blank.
How can i confirm that at one domain i have another theme different from the other domain?
(i have bought PLAZATHEMES / PORTO THEME / ROKANTHEMES)

I hope that i'm clear with question!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check the following answer if it could help you.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221447/magento-2-how-to-manage-different-theme-for-different-store

Answer (score 0):

I already seen that question,
but that response shows how to customize each store with their url.
I want to know, HOW TO CUSTOMIZE EACH STORE having 3 THEMES downloaded?
How to "deactivate" 2 themes and leave active only 1, and do this process for each domain that is available at "Scope" option.
Hope i am clear.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

1. Then you can Go to Content > Configuration (Under Design)
2. You'll see all stores here, Select Edit on store, you want to apply theme one by one.
3. Select the Theme from List under Applied Theme.
4. Save this.
5. By this you can apply any theme to any store, or same theme to all stores.
   [image]

[image]